# How to have a observable collection that can be updated from two sources without causing a loop in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am working with knockout.js. I have a situation where I have a collection of items which each have a observable boolean isleader. Where one of them can be active at a time. If people swap an item in the collection with one from another collection then I check if the old one isleader is true and if so I set it on the new one. This works fine. Now I need to add a second input mechanism which is a dropdown which is bound to the collection to show all the items from the collection. I want the one item in the collection with the isleader set to true to be the selected item and if the selected item is changed I would like the isleader to be updated to reflect this.

How can I do this without creating an infinite loop between the dropdown and the collection constantly updating the selected item.

Comment: if my answer helped you solve your problem, please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a peek.

```
this.selectedItem.peek()
```

as opposed to

```
this.selectedItem()
```

as you are propably doing.

Both will return the fields value, but the first will do it without creating a dependency. In other words, peek will get the value, but it won't subscribe to it.